# How to compare string with DateTime in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework-4

I've an Entity framework schema as below.

```
Class Contact
{ 
   string name;
   DateTime creationDate;
}
and i've a string that is

string date="9/9/14 3:00:00 PM"
```

i am executing foll0wing query

```
var q=from u in db.Contacts where u.creationDate.ToString==date select u;
```

but i am facing the following error

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

can any one tell me how can i compare dateTime with string ? what are the possible casting?

Comment: Parse your string into a DateTime object and use that in your query.

Comment: yes i did through this statement DateTime temp=Convert.ToDateTime(date);but now query is not returning any result.

Answer (score 1):

[Change your string to a DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something like (new DateTime() wont work either for the same reason as .ToString() doesn't work, i.e. Entity Framework does not know of it):

```
[EdmFunctionAttribute("Edm", "CreateDateTime")]
public static Nullable<DateTime> CreateDateTime(
    Nullable<int> year,
    Nullable<int> month,
    Nullable<int> day,
    Nullable<int> hour,
    Nullable<int> minute,
    Nullable<double> second
)
```

Parameters

year
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The year part of the new date.
```

month
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The month part of the new date.
```

day
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The day part of the new date.
```

hour
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The hour part of the new date.
```

minute
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The minutes part of the new date.
```

second
    Type: System.Nullable

```
The seconds part of the new date. Note that you can specify fractions of a second with this parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("9/9/14 3:00:00 PM");

var q from u in db.Contacts
      where u.creationDate == date
      select u;
```

Comment: it does not return any result although "9/9/14 3:00:00 PM" is present in database

Comment: Is the date definitely being parsed correctly? You could try using ParseExact to be sure: `DateTime.ParseExact("9/9/14 3:00:00 PM", "M/d/yy h:00:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: when i parse through your method then i faced the following error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Is your date string definitely "9/9/14 3:00:00 PM"? Running the exact code posted in my previous comment  parses fine for me.

Comment: yes. parsing is fine now but comparison fails. i don't get any data

Comment: I would sugegst to try the below query first
var q from u in db.Contacts
      where u.creationDate == new DateTime(2014, 9, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0);
      select u;



And this will let us know if the issue is with parsing the string or  while adding the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Contact>  t = new List<Contact>();

String date="9/9/14 3:00:00 PM"

var result = t.Where(m => m.creationDate == DateTime.ParseExact(date,"M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt",null));
```

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. error occurs

Answer (score 0):

try to split the date into parts.

```
 string dt = "9/9/14 3:00:00 PM";
 var date =  DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt",null);

 var q from u in db.Contacts
      .Where (u.creationDate.DateTime.Year <= date.Year
                   && u.creationDate.DateTime.Month <= date.Month
                   && u.creationDate.DateTime.Day <= date.Day
                    && u.creationDate.DateTime.Day <= date.Hour
                    && u.creationDate.DateTime.Day <= date.Minute
                    && u.creationDate.DateTime.Day <= date.Second
                   )
        select u;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var result = t.Where(m => m.creationDate == DateTime.ParseExact(date,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt",null));
```

The date stored in sql server is in yyyy-MM-dd format.